Solving recursion with substitution method $9T(\frac{n}{3}) + O(n^2)$
A tight upperbound for $T(n)= 9T(n/3) + O(n^2)$ for $n>1$ needs to be found by substitution method. For the claim $T(n) \leq cn^2\log n$, I ended up finding $T(n)\leq cn^2\log n-cn^2+c_1n^2$. Which can mean that when $c>c_1 $, $T(n)\leq cn^2\log n-(\text{someting})$ holds and we found an upperbound $ O(n^2\log n)$. However, if we were to say $T(k)\geq ck^2\log k$ for $k<n$ and tried to find a lower bound the same way can't we just pick $c_1>c$ this time and this way its also a lowerbound $\Omega(n^2\log n)$ or am I wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Do you mean $T(n)=9T(n/3)+O(n^2)$?

@J.G. yes, sorry

I can offer you a more direct method. Making $n = 3^m$ we can recast the recurrence as
$$
R(m) = 3^2R(m-1)+\mu (3^2)^m,\ \ \mu\in \mathbb{R}
$$
where
$$
R_h(m) = (3^2)^m c_0
$$
now making the particular as $R_p(m) = (3^2)^mc(m)$ after substitution into the complete recurrence we get
$$
(3^2)^mc(m) = (3^2)^m c(m-1) + \mu (3^2)^m
$$
or
$$
c(m) = \mu m
$$
then $R_p(m) = (3^2)^m\mu m$ hence
$$
R(m) = R_h(m)+R_p(m) = (c_0+\mu m)(3^2)^m
$$
now going backwards with $m = \log_3 n$ we have finally
$$
T(n) = (c_0+\mu \log_3 n)n^2\Rightarrow T(n) \approx O(n^2\log n)
$$
